# JQuery .hide function works okay with text fields but assigns a particular value to select box elements

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox "Experience" in a div (say id = "exp").
If the user select yes, a hidden div is shown (say id = "fill_details").
I am using the jQuery hide and show.
The issue is, on clicking checkbox Experience yes for the first time, hidden div shows up with elements (textboxes and selectboxes.)
Then on clicking checkbox Experience No the div again hides out, even this is okay.
But on clicking Yes again, the textboxes are blank (which I want) but the select boxes are assigned the last select options by itself. (This I dont want.)

What I want is "Every time user click yes on Experience checkbox, the div must show up with with no default values."

Here is the code that I am using:

@DavidThomas: Below is the HTML

```
<div id="exp" class="row">      
        <?php
        print drupal_render($form['submitted']['employment_history']['employer_1']['experience']);
         }
         ?>
    </div>
<div id="fill_details" >
    <div class="row">       
        <?php
        print drupal_render($form['submitted']['employment_history']['employer_1']['name_of_employer']);
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">       
        <?php
        print drupal_render($form['submitted']['employment_history']['employer_1']['starting_salary']);
         }
         ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JQuery I am using for the same.

```
if($("#exp").is(':checked'))  {
    $('#fill_details').show();
}
else {
    $('#fill_details').hide();
    $('#fill_details *').val('');
}
```

The experience element above is a radio-button and the salary is select box. 
Please help, I am not able to understand where the issue is.
Thanks.

Comment: can u add http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please show the relevant html; describing it is far more ambiguous and less useful than you might imagine.

Comment: You need an empty option in the select box and select that via code whenever you show it.

Comment: @Malai: I am not able to create a jsfiddle. Firstly, I never created one before. Secondly, the html is using drupal_render, which is not generating any result in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: why do you add * after #fill_details  in else part?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a "blank" value in your select box? If not, try this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">Please select an option</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nmaF/)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to reset the value.

```
if($("#exp").is(':checked'))  {

    $('#fill_details').show();
}
else  {
    $('#fill_details').hide();
    $('#fill_details *').val('');
    **$('#fill_details select option:first').attr('selected','selected');**
}
```

But it would be easier to tell with something like a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use jquery `toggle()` method for hide/unhide a div on checkbox checked/unchecked,

```
$("#exp").click(function() {
  $("#fill_details").toggle();
});
```

Comment: The issue is the appearance of the default values and not with hide and show. Will toggle help with that ?